# The procedure "SP_name" has no parameter named "@typ_table" in dapper.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, task, dapper

### What I Want.

If user enter duplicated value, then i want to delete that duplicate value and install the new one. I don't want to use update query because of some requirement.

---

### Code:

**Web API**

```
public CoCApiResponse CreateVersion(CreateVersion versionObj)
{
 var taskForDelete = Task.Run(() => 
 versionRepository.DeleteVersions(objVersionCollection));
 taskForDelete.Wait();
 versionRepository.CreateVersion(versionObj.version, lstVersion).Result;
}
```

---

**Repository:**

```
public async Task<Version> DeleteVersions(CoCBaseCollection<Version> Versions)
        {
            List<Version> versionList = new List<Version>();
            foreach (var objVersion in Versions)
            {
                Version version = new Version()
                {
                    Id = objVersion.Id,
                    VersionName = objVersion.VersionName,
                    StructureWeek = objVersion.StructureWeek,
                    IsWLTP = objVersion.IsWLTP,
                    VersionStatusTypeId = objVersion.VersionStatusTypeId,
                    CreatedDateTime = System.DateTime.Now,
                    LastUpdatedDateTime = System.DateTime.Now
                };
                versionList.Add(version);
            }
            int retval = 0;
            DataTable dtVersions = TableConversion.EnitiesToDataTable<Version>(versionList);
            pars = new DynamicParameters();
            pars.Add("@VersionTableForDelete", dtVersions.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.VersionTable"));
            pars.Add("@Retval", retval, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);

            string DeleteVersionSP = "dbo.DeleteVersions";
            return await ExecSproc<Version>(DeleteVersionSP, pars, new Version()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

public async Task<Version> CreateVersion(Version version, List<Version> versions)
        {
            int retval = 0;
            DataTable dtVersions = TableConversion.EnitiesToDataTable<Version>(versions);
            pars.Add("@refVersionTable", dtVersions.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.VersionTable"));
            pars.Add("@Retval", retval, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);

            string CreateVersionSP = "dbo.SPCreateVersion";
            return await ExecSproc<Version>(CreateVersionSP, pars, version).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

---

### Problem

I am getting this below error, while I am running the Delete and Create method

> The procedure "SPCreateVersion" has no parameter named "@VersionTableForDelete".

---

### What I have tried.

I have checked with my Store Procedure and it's working fine and also searched more than  2 hour from google But I am unable to resolve it. Because no one given the exact solution for `dapper.net`

---

### Finally, What I found :

Yeah! It is working while doing delete and  insert **separately**

```
public CoCApiResponse CreateVersion(CreateVersion versionObj)
    {     
     versionRepository.CreateVersion(versionObj.version).Result;// working 
    } 
//
 public CoCApiResponse CreateVersion(CreateVersion versionObj)
    {
     var taskForDelete = Task.Run(() => 
     versionRepository.DeleteVersions(versionObj));//working
     taskForDelete.Wait();
    }
```

> **But it is throwing the error while inserting, if we are doing both delete and insert.**

```
public CoCApiResponse CreateVersion(CreateVersion versionObj)
    {
     var taskForDelete = Task.Run(() => 
     versionRepository.DeleteVersions(versionObj));//working
     taskForDelete.Wait();
     versionRepository.CreateVersion(versionObj.version).Result;// Not Working and throwing an error
    }
```

---

### What I Guess

this error may be related with asyn/sync callback problem. But I don't have any idea to resolve this.

---

*How can we resolve this?*

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved while I clear the parameters before adding a new parameters  in `CreateVersion` Store Procedure

like

`pars = new DynamicParameters();`

Full code is

```
public async Task<Version> CreateVersion(Version version, List<Version> versions)
        {
            int retval = 0;
            DataTable dtVersions = TableConversion.EnitiesToDataTable<Version>(versions);
            pars = new DynamicParameters();// this line  resolved the issue
            pars.Add("@refVersionTable", dtVersions.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.VersionTable"));
            pars.Add("@Retval", retval, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            string CreateVersionSP = "dbo.SPCreateVersion";
            return await ExecSproc<Version>(CreateVersionSP, pars, version).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```